# Want to start few services automatically during system boot

Tags: autostart, nagios3, telnet

I am using latest ubuntu version: Ubuntu 15.04 (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-36-generic x86_64)

When i reboot my whole system, i need to restart ***telnet, nagios*** services manually.

Would you please let me know how to add this in crontask or any other easy way to do that. So, that i don't need to restart those services manually.

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/618133/edit) your question and add the Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has a program where you can set certain programs to run at startup. I'm in KDE right now, so I can't get the exact name, but it should come up with a search of `startup`. Here, point to the script you use to start the services (make sure the script is executable) and apply. If you use commands to start the services, make a `.sh` file with `#!bin/bash` at the top and your commands below. If you start the two services with programs, find the paths to those and point the `startup` app to them.

If this is completely wrong, tell me: I'll delete it.

Comment: OP wants to start services.

Comment: @A.B. Is this completely wrong?

Comment: Certainly not. :)

Comment: What should I change? My terminology?

Comment: eg: http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux

Comment: @Zacharee1, its little bit confusing for me. Would you like to describe me briefly?

Comment: I can't do it now, but remind me in about 6 hours.

Comment: @ Zacharee1- a soft reminder for you... :)

Comment: Oh god. Sorry. I'm in school right now. What timezone are you in? I'm done at 2:15 eastern.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility to start application on boot can be done with crontab.

Example

/etc/crontab

```
 @reboot    root    /usr/local/bin/your-programm.sh
```

The @reboot will also apply when you only boot your system.